# Moving from react-create-app to production grade

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on react since last few months. I am struggling with this issue since a long time and did all the research but got more confused. Till now I have used "create-react-app" and boilerplates like this https://github.com/NipuniBhagya/Simple-React-Boilerplate for making react projects. I know this cannot be a project with can be of production grade. I want to have a project having something like this structure

[image]

How am I supposed to proceed from those simple create-react-app to something like this? THere are a lot of boilerplates which confuses me a lot.

Comment: Why can't you use CRA in production?

Comment: I still have to add server files, webpack etc right?

Answer (score 0):

No. That's the whole point of CRA. Everything is already set up.

Comment: What if I want to have a webpack file and config files in cra? Also things like ACL, Server side rendering has to be included for my application.

Comment: Also what if I want to edit the webpack file which CRA uses?

Comment: @ApurvG In that case you can use eject. It's written about that in the CRA documentation. And nothing stops you from having server files in the same folder structure as the react app.